# tcpdf generates pdf.html document in safari(Mac)

Tags: php, macos, pdf, safari, tcpdf

Tcpdf generates pdf as filename.pdf.html in safari Mac and it loads as html file not as pdf file. what parameters should I set to download it as pdf in safari?

It is working fine in all other browsers.

Here is my function:

```
$pdf_content = $libTcpdf->downloadReceipt((string) $view->render());
$pdf_content->Output("Receipt.pdf", 'D');
```

html page is stored in a view.

In tcpdf.php(tcpdf library)

```
case 'D': {
    // download PDF as file
    if (ob_get_contents()) {
        $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
    }
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    if (headers_sent()) {
        $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
    }
    header('Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=1');
    //header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    // force download dialog
    if (strpos(php_sapi_name(), 'cgi') === false) {
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
        header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
    } else {
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    }
    // use the Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    $this->sendOutputData($this->getBuffer(), $this->bufferlen);
    break;
}
```

Content-type is set to application/pdf.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Downloading pdf file in safari is not working as expected. It downloads as pdf.html. It is working fine in other browsers